# Why omnet++ did not generate get method for a class member defined in .msg file?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I made a little changes in a .msg file in INET source codes. Generally, the .h and .cc files are automatically generated by omnet++. However, there isn't a get file cooresponding to the new defined class member, while the cooresponding set method is automatically generated. what my modification codes are as follows.

```
    class Ieee80211AckFrame extends Ieee80211OneAddressHeader
{
chunkLength = LENGTH_ACK - B(4);
type = ST_ACK;
bool isArrivedDestination; // added by Axida
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it does not generate a getter?

Please note that for `bool` parameters the getter function will **NOT** have a `get` prefix, i.e. while for `int myParam` the message compiler will generate `getMyParam()` and `setMyParam()`, for `bool isRight` you will get `setIstRight()` and `isRight()` (**NOT** `getIsRight()`)